# Finding the largest number returns wrong value when i have few double digit numbers in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to find the largest number in an array. But my code gives the correct value only if all numbers are single digit. If I include a double digit number, It wont consider it.

```js
const numb = ['7', '10', '8', '6', '7'];
let arr1 = numb[0];
for (let i = 1; i < numb.length; i++) {
  if (numb[i] >= arr1) {
    arr1 = numb[i];
  }
}

console.log(arr1);
```

```js
const numb = ['7', '9', '8', '6', '7'];
let arr1 = numb[0];
for (let i = 1; i < numb.length; i++) {
  if (numb[i] >= arr1) {
    arr1 = numb[i];
  }
}

console.log(arr1);
```

The first code gives me output 8, when it should be 10.
while the second one gives me 9.
What am I missing here?

Comment: @JamieTaylorSangerman, that's an answer, not a comment on how to improve the question.

Comment: can't believe i overlooked this. Thank you for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing strings - and these are compared lexicographically.

```js
const numb = [7, 10, 8, 6, 7];
let arr1 = numb[0];
for (let i = 1; i < numb.length; i++) {
  if (numb[i] >= arr1) {
    arr1 = numb[i];
  }
}
console.log(arr1);
```

Also note that the simplest way to find the largest number in an array is to use `Math.max` with spreading.

```js
const numb = [7, 10, 8, 6, 7];
let arr1 = Math.max(...numb);
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings, it should be numbers.

`const numb = [7,10,8,6,7];`

`'7' > '10'` is true , it compares 7 with 1

Answer (score 0):

The `numb` arrays are full of strings, not numbers. You can either change the arrays to be numbers, or use `parseInt()` if you don't want to edit the original arrays.

```
const numb = ['7','10','8','6','7'];
let arr1 = numb[0];
for (let i=1 ; i < numb.length ; i++)
{
 if(parseInt(numb[i]) >= parseInt(arr1)){
 arr1 = numb[i];
}
} console.log(arr1);


const numb = ['7','9','8','6','7'];
let arr1 = numb[0];
for (let i=1 ; i < numb.length ; i++)
{
if(parseInt(numb[i]) >= parseInt(arr1)){
 arr1 = numb[i];
}
} console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

your array `numb` is of type `string`. so really, your loop isn't for example checking that `1 > 2` but that "1" lexicographically (alphabetically) comes after "2". A **string** "10" isn't necessarily larger than "8" different than how the **number** 10 clearly is the larger. Change your array to an array of numbers instead of strings. `const numb = [1, 5, 6, 2, 33]`.

Answer (score 0):

You code works if the array is array of numbers but since it is not you have to cast to number:

```js
const numb = ['7','10','8','6','7'];
let arr1 = +numb[0];
for (let i=1 ; i < numb.length ; i++) {
   if(+numb[i] >= +arr1){
     arr1 = +numb[i];
   }
} console.log(arr1); // 10
```

As you can see this now works since we casted via the `+` all the strings to numbers. You can do it that way or simply convert the entire array to numbers **before** you start iterating over it and leave your other code as is.

Just as FYI there are more concise ways to achieve this result:

Since you have an array on strings and you are trying to find a number the preferred route is to convert that array of strings to numbers and then simply utilize `Math.max` like this:

```js
const arr = ['7','10','8','6','9'];  // <-- array of strings
 
let r = Math.max(...arr.map(x => +x))  // <-- cast to number and find max

console.log(r) // 10
```

Another option if you really have to work with strings is to sort the array in descending order and take the first element like this:

```js
const arr = ['7','10','8','6','9'];

let r = arr.sort((a,b) => b.localeCompare(a, undefined, { numeric: true }))[0]

console.log(r) // 10
```

This utilizes the [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method with its `numeric: true` option which takes into account numbers in strings when sorting.